# How to make a model automatically reload and fetch data when the data in the DB changes?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

How to automatically reload the `model` after the data in ember-mirage has changed?

I mean: After performing a `$.post()` operation on ember mirage data, schema is changed. This has to be reflected in the template. But, since the model for the template is already run, the model hook is not run again!

I am using `ember-cli-mirage` for the past few days.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using Ember Data (which I would strongly recommend), you’ll need to use ‘model.set’ and ‘model.save’ for the model to be automatically updated.

If you’re not, and you ‘$.post’ some changes to the server, you’ll need to refetch whatever data you changed.